# Keystonejs - Querying items in Relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, keystonejs

I want to write a query to filter the content that has relationships set on it.

Laptopy.js

```
 var keystone = require('keystone');
    var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

    var Laptop = new keystone.List('Laptop', {
       map: { name: 'nazwa' },
       autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'nazwa', unique: true },
    });

    Laptop.add({
       nazwa:{type: String, required: true},
       grafika:{type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'KartaGraficzna'}

    });
    Laptop.register();
```

KartaGraficzna.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var KartaGraficzna = new keystone.List('KartaGraficzna', {
   map: { name: 'nazwa' },
   autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'nazwa', unique: true },
});

KartaGraficzna.add({
   nazwa:{type: String, required: true},
   producent:{type: Types.Select, options: 'nVidia, AMD, Intel'},
});

KartaGraficzna.relationship({ ref: 'Laptop', path: 'grafika' });
KartaGraficzna.register();
```

QUERY

```
var Laptop = keystone.list('laptops');
Laptop.model.find()
   .populate('grafika')
   .where('grafika.nazwa', 'GTX980')
   .exec(function (err, laptop) {
      locals.data.laptopy = laptop;
      next(err);
   });
```

I know this query is wrong and this not works like that.
Can someone tell me how to do this?
I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Very much unclear problem statement.=> **filter the content that has relationships set on it.**

What should I understand out of it. and that too when you give some contradicting  code example. ?

Any way , If I go by words  `filter the content that has relationships set`. **I assume that you dont want to see those laptops for which  grafika   is set**.

So my answer is, just  compare with null.

```
Laptop.model.find()
     .where('grafika', null)
     .exec(function (err, laptop) {
         locals.data.laptopy = laptop;
         next(err);
      });
```